# Inherit vales from Parent class to Child class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a Parent class that has default values . That all other objects inherit.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, a, b, x, y):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b, x, y):
        super().__init__(self, a, b)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I want to `Parent` and `Child` have the same `a` and `b` . So I don't want to write all the time:

```
v = Child(a,b,x,y)
```

but:

```
v = Child(x,y)
```

Comment: What do you expect `a` and `b` to be, if you don't pass them in? Is python just supposed to pick a random number or string or object?

Comment: When you do inheritance, you don't have a parent/child relationship. If you have a class of `Dog` and a subclass of `Poodle`, the `Poodle` isn't a child of `Dog`.

Comment: Your `a` and `b` (and `x`, `y` and `z` too) attributes do not belong to the classes, but to _instances_ of the classes, so what you ask for ("I want to Parent and Child have the same a and b") doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your `Child.__init__` makes no sense. `Parent.__init__` expects 4 arguments, you are passing in 3, and `self` should not be one of those to begin with. You'd use `super().__init__(a, b, x, y)`, but then you'd redundantly set `x` and `y` *again*. You could just remove all of the `Child.__init__` method. Alternatively, if `Parent()` should not have `x` and `y` attributes, you should remove them from the `Parent.__init__` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you'll have multiple `Parent()` instances and that you want to create `Child()` instances using defaults of *one* of those.

You could create a factory method on the parent:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, a, b, x, y):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def create_child(self, x, y):
        return Child(self.a, self.b, x, y)

child = parent.create_child(x, y)
```

or give `Child` a factory class method:

```
class Child(Parent):
    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, parent, x, y):
        return cls(parent.a, parent.b, x, y)
```

and use that:

```
child = Child.from_parent(parent, x, y)
```

Pick the method that best fit how your algorithm needs to produce child nodes.

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> parent = Parent('foo', 'bar', 10, 20)
>>> child = Child.from_parent(parent, 52, 1)
>>> vars(child)
{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar', 'x': 52, 'y': 1}
```

Comment: classmethod is not working.

Comment: @MarkoBerger: 'not working' doesn't tell me anything. Do you get an exception? Is it returning the wrong result? What?

Comment: from_parent () you have 4 arguments and when you call them you are passing them only 3. So Im getting an error

Comment: @MarkoBerger: your `Child.__init__` method called `super().__init__()` passing in `self` and only `x` and `y`, but your `Parent` class expects `a`, `b` and `x`, `y`; you can remove the whole `Child.__init__` instead.

Comment: @MarkoBerger: it was not the classmethod that was the issue, it was your own `Child.__init__` definition.

Comment: Error msg is : AttributeError: type object 'Parent' has no 'a'

Comment: @MarkoBerger: then you are not passing in a proper `Parent` instance. See the demo.

Comment: Thx it's WORKING.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use class variables then?

```
class Parent():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    pass

v = Child(x,y)
```

Answer (score -1):

Class `Parent` does not seem to have default values for attributes `a` and `b`. I recommend you do this minor change to your code by using class variables

```
class Parent():
    a = 'foo'
    b = 'bar'
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```